I recently updated android studio to 2024.2.1 ladybug. I have errors with firebase dependencies
here's the error log. I changed my gradle wrapper to 8.4 and tried building an apps without firebase and it worked but the apps with firebase gave these logs
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
ERROR:C:\Users\DELL i7 8th gen\AndroidStudioProjects\uni_share\build\firebase_core\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR:C:\Users\DELL i7 8th gen\AndroidStudioProjects\uni_share\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR:C:\Users\DELL i7 8th gen\AndroidStudioProjects\uni_share\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :cloud_firestore) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.1, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\DELL i7 8th gen\AndroidStudioProjects\uni_share\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 46s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to recompile my code after the update.

Please edit  your question and show us your  Gradle files.

Have you found a solution?

I had some similar errors after the latest Android Studio update with my flutter project. If it is not your case, maybe, it will help someone passing by.
Ended up removing android/ folder from the project root.
Then flutter create . and, finally,  flutter run.
PS: Just to think of it, to call their software 'LadyBug'...
